# If the derivative of a function is the zero function in $\mathbb R^n$, then the function is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, connectedness

If the derivative of a function is the zero function in $\mathbb R^n$, then the function is constant. Basically I am considering $f: \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ and $Df(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^m$. The general fact is that If the derivative of a function is the zero function in $\mathbb R^n$, then the function is constant when the domain is path-connected but I am not getting any proof over math stack.
In $1$ dimension we can use LMVT but from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ this is of no use. I think we have to deal with path and then locally constant. I don't know the proof of locally constant as well. If someone can help me from the scratch I can also fill up the details if I can follow it. Someone can also mention some books if those have the answer.

Comment: You should be able to reduce back to a function from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. Pick two points $x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ (if you can). The vectors should disagree in some coordinate (say, the $i$th). Then consider the function $x \mapsto (f(x))_i$ along the line segment between $x_1$ and $x_2$. The mean value theorem should apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,y\in \mathbb R^m$ then the map $g:t\mapsto ty+(1-t)x$ is well-defined. Then, with $h:=f\circ g$, we can find $t\in (0,1)$ such that $|h(1)-h(0)|\le |h'(t)|.^{1}$

But $h(1)-h(0)=|f(y)-f(x)|$ and $h'(t)=Df(g(t))\circ g'(t)=0.$ It follows that $f(x)=f(y).$

$1.$ This is the mean-value inequality for vector-valued functions. Rudin proves it this way: define $z:=h(1)-h(0)$ and $\varphi(t)=\langle z,h(t)\rangle$ and apply the single-variable mean-value theorem to find a $c\in (0,1)$ such that $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\varphi'(c)=\langle z,h'(c)\rangle.$ But we also have $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=|z|^2$ so the result follows by the Schwarz inequality.